# How to unpin and remove specific flatpak packages?

Tags: flatpak

I am getting messages like this:

```
Info: (pinned) runtime org.freedesktop.Platform branch 21.08 is end-of-life, with reason:
   org.freedesktop.Platform 21.08 is no longer receiving fixes and security updates. 
Please update to a supported runtime version.

Info: runtime org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default branch 21.08 is end-of-life, with reason:
   org.freedesktop.Platform 21.08 is no longer receiving fixes and security updates. 
Please update to a supported runtime version.
```

How can I force remove these outdated and unused pinned flatpak dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here is to first unpin the specific versions. To do this you need to pass in the full "path" of the pinned flatpak package to the "pin" command with some flags, as follows.

**First, try to uninstall unused packages using a simple command:**

```
flatpak uninstall --unused
```

**Next, look at the output you get:**

```
These runtimes in installation 'system' are pinned and won't be removed; see flatpak-pin(1):
  runtime/org.freedesktop.Sdk/x86_64/21.08

These runtimes in installation 'user' are pinned and won't be removed; see flatpak-pin(1):
  runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/21.08
Nothing unused to uninstall
```

Notice the full path of the runtimes such as: `runtime/org.freedesktop.Sdk/x86_64/21.08`

**Now, unpin those packages:**

```
flatpak pin --remove runtime/org.freedesktop.Sdk/x86_64/21.08
# add the --user flag if it is a user package, e.g.:
flatpak pin --user --remove runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/21.08
```

**Important: if the package is a `user` package, you MUST add `--user` to the pin command.**

**Finally, run the uninstall unused command again and they should get removed:**

```
flatpak uninstall --unused
```